# Create a calculated field using values to create a slicer in excel pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, slice, calculated-field, vba

I have a data set where one column (job type) has 4 values in it (A,B,C,D).  I am using that column as a slicer in a pivot table.  However I would like to modify this slicer to only have two options (X,Y) where X=A+B  and Y=C+D.  I know I could create a new column in the raw data but I am trying to avoid this as the raw data source is already highly manipulated through several dozen high complexity mods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies if this isn't clear!

This is tested on Excel 2010.

I'm assuming that you have your pivot table setup with the items you want to slice as the row labels.

Select the "A" label, ctrl click the "B" label, and then right click, selecting "Group".  Do the same thing for the "C" and "D" entries.  You will notice a new field in the Field List and in the Row Labels section.

Clean up by changing the name of the new label, and the new groups.

Drag it out of the Row Labels area.  Your pivot table should look like it did before, but with a new field available.  Insert a slicer, using that field as the selection field.

Have a look at a quick video I made here:  http://youtu.be/QIcZPGxisKM

Comment: Did you look at the video?  It did exactly what i thought you asked.

Comment: wholly crap, can't believe I missed that part.  I try the group piece but missed the taking it back out of row and it kept it.  The video was great.  Thank you!

Comment: <bow> My pleasure!  I remember the joy when I recently discovered how to do this.